# Metasploit Development Reference

Tags: network, metasploit

The Metasploit team provides some documentation on how to develop exploits, but other than looking through the sourcecode (which is annoying considering how much time I spend going from this file to that file) is there any other semi-comprehensive reference that would make it much easier to learn about the framework? Such as discussing common functions, but in more detail than the documentation found on Metasploit's website.

Comment: Learning to read source code is important. The ability to learn about a code base by efficiently reading source is indispensable in the programming and security fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have video series on developing exploits with metasploit here
http://www.securitytube.net/groups?operation=viewall&groupId=0

Here are some other links
http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Useful_API_Calls

http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Exploit_Development

http://dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/wiki/ExploitModuleDev

http://www.nullthreat.net/2011/01/fuzzing-and-exploit-development-with.html

http://www.securitytube.net/video/2321

http://dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/repository/entry/HACKING

Also i recommend looking at exploits similar to what you want to do to see how they work.

Answer (score 1):

The last chapters of the excellent book "[Metasploit: The Penetration Tester's Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/159327288X)" are dedicated to Metasploit development.